# int_rate =float(input('Enter the annualized interest rate in percentage:'))

Tags: python-3.x

what is wrong with this problem:

```
int_rate=float(input('Enter the annualized interest rate in percenage:')
```

It want let me run because it gives me an error saying that it cannot convert string into float. I'm confused

Comment: Well, what did you type in when prompted to enter the rate?

Comment: You can only convert the string to a float if the string is actually a valid number. This means you aren't allowed, for example, a `%` sign. If you want to be able to enter that, then maybe use `float(input('...').strip('%'))`

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: missing  parenthesis - aslo not describing what Input you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot convert strings directly into integers if there are any non-integer characters in the string. Your prompt about annualized interest rate percentages may make the user input a string such as "3%" which would contain the non-integer character "%."

To remedy this problem, you can try formatting the string before processing it.

```
input_string = input("Enter the annualized interest rate in percenage:")
int_rate = float(input_string[:-1] if input_string[-1] == "%" else input_string)
```